# flask UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm learning the flask module 
I copy the code but it didn't work and give my the UnicodeDecodeError
[image: here is the code and error]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the traceback point out, your computer's hostname has non-ASCII character. As [this document](https://bugs.python.org/issue9377) said, you can use this way to get your hostname:

```
$ python
>>> from socket import *
>>> getnameinfo(("127.0.0.1", 0), 0)
('user-greyli', '0')  # here the 'user-greyli' is hostname
```

In windows system, the hostname was same as computer's name. So, you need to rename your computer's name.

How to do it? Just check [this page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajnx). Besides, as a bonus, I capture a picture in Chinese that includes all the operation you need :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a python bug, with non-ascii characters in the hostname. This issue should have been solved with https://bugs.python.org/issue26226, but could have been reintroduced with https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0529 and changes in `getfilesystemencoding`.

Easiest way is to change our hostname to contain only ascii characters.